# If $H$ is open, is the set $H^{\perp \perp} \setminus H$ closed in $\mathbb{R}?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $H\subseteq\mathbb{R}.$
We denote $H^c$ and $\overline{H}$ as complement and closure of $H$ respectively.

Recall that $x\in \overline{H}$ if and only if for any open set $O$ containing $x,$ the intersection $O$ and $H$ is nonempty.

Let $H^\perp = (\overline{H})^c.$

> **Question:** Suppose that $H$ is open. Is the set $H^{\perp \perp} - H$ closed in $\mathbb{R}?$

I have a feeling that the set above is indeed close in $\mathbb{R}$ because any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals. Then closure of open interval just add two endpoints.

However, I am unable to prove it. 
Any hint would be appreciated.

**Motivation:** I am reading [Measure and Category by Oxtoby](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387905082). In chapter $4,$ the author introduced the following definition.

> A set is called *regular open* if $int(\overline{A})=A.$

It can be shown that every regular set satisfies $A^{\perp \perp} = A.$

The following lemma can be obtained in the same chapter.

> **Lemma:** Every open set $H$ can be expressed as $H = G - \overline{N}$ where $G$ is regular open and $N$ is nowhere dense.

In the proof, the author define $G = H^{\perp \perp}$ and $N = G- H.$
Then $N$ is nowhere dense. 
I am wondering whether the set $N$ is closed or not. 
I have an example which shows that $N$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 2.$
But my example does not work in $\mathbb{R}.$
That is why I am asking the question above.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't have to be closed. Let $D=\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb N, n>1\}\subset (0,1).$ Take $H=(0,1)\setminus D.$ Then $H^\perp=\mathbb R\setminus [0,1]$ and $H^{\perp\perp}=(0,1),$ so $H^{\perp\perp}\setminus H=D$ which is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false.

Consider the set $H=\mathbb Q$.
Then $H^\perp=\emptyset$.
On the other hand, $\emptyset^\perp=\mathbb R$.
Finally, you can see that $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ is not closed.

Comment: I apologize my mistake in my post. $H$ must be open.